# Updating state multiple times within a setTimeout

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have some code in React that basically set's state in a series of timeouts. The idea is to gradually change the values in the array one after the other.

```
  const clickHandler = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const newValues = [...values];
        newValues[i] = "-";
        setValues(newValues);
      }, (i + 1) * 500);
    }
  };
```

However, i notice that only the latest values get updated (and the previous ones flip back to their original state). It seems like the setValues don't update by the time subsequent timeouts are called. Maybe the setValues are getting batched together.

I could refactor code to maybe use another variable and make changes in useEffect but just wanted to confirm my understanding of why this issue is happening.

Comment: You're looking for the callback form of setting state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a minimal, verifiable example. You need to use a [functional update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) because `values` refers to the original value each time. I am recommending `async` and `await` because they offer better control flow compared to the antiquated `setTimeout`.

```js
async function onClick(event) {
  for (const [index, _] of values.entries()) {
    setValues(v => [
      ...v.slice(0, index),
      "",
      ...v.slice(index + 1)
    ])
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 500))
  }
}
```

StackOverflow doesn't support `async` and `await` in React snippets so I had to use `reduce` and `promise.then`. <kbd>Run</kbd> to see how functional updates solve your problem.

```js
const sleep = ms =>
  new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))

const update = (arr, index, f) =>
  [...arr.slice(0, index), f(arr[index]), ...arr.slice(index + 1)]

function App() {
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState(["", "", "", ""])
  function onClick(event) {
    values.reduce((prom, value, index) =>
      prom
        .then(_ => sleep(500))
        .then(_ => setValues(v => update(v, index, _ => ""))),
      Promise.resolve()
    )
  }
  return <p>
    {values.join(" ")}<br/>
    Let's eat! <button onClick={onClick} children="いただきます" />
  </p>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
p { margin: 0; font-size: 4rem; line-height: 4rem; font-family: sans-serif; }
button { font-size: 2rem; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```